# How to solve "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found" error with Realtek RTL8852BE WiFi 6 802.11ax PCIe in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, realtek, realtek-wireless

I have a dual boot with Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 11 freshly installed, but my Wi-Fi is not working. It states that "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found". The card is a Realtek RTL8852BE WiFi 6 802.11ax.

The result of terminal command `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` is:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b852]
    DeviceName: Realtek Wireless LAN + BT
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:88e3]
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Micron Technology Inc Device [1344:5404] (rev 03)
```

My laptop has an AMD Ryzen 7 5825U processor and AMD Radeon graphics. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For informational purposes I wonder if you could tell me what laptop brand and model number this issue relates to.  I am considering making a new purchase for my significant other and wish to avoid these issues if possible.  I've been through a wifi driver conflict once before, it could be pertinent to many others in the future.  Thank you :)  perhaps add it to the question information.

Comment: here is the link: https://www.hp.com/in-en/shop/hp-pavilion-laptop-14-ec1008au-6d9t4pa.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**EDIT**: Please remove the incorrect driver package:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:kelebek333/kablosuz 
sudo apt purge rtw89-dkms 
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git bc
git clone https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be.git
cd rtl8852be
make
```

Several possibly harmless warnings will appear.

```
sudo make install
```

Reboot. You will probably need to disable secure boot.

After each kernel update, you must recompile:

```
cd rtl8852be
make clean
git pull
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: sorry to say but after running the above commands and disabling the secure boot nothing changes :(

Comment: May we please see: `sudo dmesg | grep -i rtw`

Comment: this command  "sudo dmesg | grep -i rtw" returned me nothing.

Comment: Please try: `sudo modprobe rtw89pci && sudo dmesg | grep -i rtw` Post any errors, warnings, etc.

Comment: The error is: [13076.955807] rtw89core: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[13076.955887] rtw89core: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel

Comment: Those are not errors; they are informational. Which driver loaded? `lsmod | grep rtw` Is there no other entries at all in dmesg related to rtw??

Comment: rtw89pci               49152  0
rtw89core             352256  1 rtw89pci
mac80211             1228800  2 rtw89pci,rtw89core
cfg80211              958464  2 rtw89core,mac80211

Comment: Please run: `sudo dmesg > dmesg.txt` Find the text file and post it here and give me the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: link: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/BHNWQGjkcy/plain/

Comment: I have slowly become convinced that, despite contrary evidence here at AU and elsewhere, that the current versions of rtw89pci are incorrect for your device. I will accordingly edit my question.

Comment: these instructions worked for me on a Lenovo IdeaBook 1

Comment: thanks buddy thanks a lot. But there is another problem that my bluetooth is not showing me any devices.

Comment: Start a new topic for the bluetooth.

Comment: yes I have posted a new question

Comment: I'm having exact problem, but i'm stuck on command `make` running this command giving following error https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/dNPMndsZd4/ please help

Comment: @ShubhamKumar Please start your own new question.

Comment: Regarding disabling safe boot: I don't want to keep safe boot disabled because it interferes with dual booting into windows. I was successfully able to create a signing certificate and sign the driver using the instructions from here: https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-sign-things-for-secure-boot.

Answer (score 4):

This solved my WIFI:

```
git clone https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be.git
```

and Bluetooth worked after:

```
git clone https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be_bt.git.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
#Turn off your Security Boot in BIOS

git clone https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be.git
cd rtl8852be
make -j8
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8852be
```

Comment: Had this same problem on an HP Pavilion Laptop 14z-ec100 running a Ryzen 5 5625U with the exact same wifi card & this worked! Can't wait until that driver finally gets into the Kernel since WiFi still doesn't work out the box on Fedora 37's 6.0 Kernel either.

Answer (score 1):

After some tinkering, I got this to work on a new Lenovo ThinkBook G2 (took longer than necessary because I didn't check the README). If your kernel version is 5.18 (check with `uname -r`) or above, you need to use:

```
git clone https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be.git -b dev
```

to get the correct version. Other steps are the same as in [chili555's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1412264/618353). Make sure Secure Boot is disabled if you run into problems.

Hope my addition helps someone, and thank you [chili555](https://askubuntu.com/users/19421/chili555)!

Comment: Thank you!!  After finally finding chili555's answer, I was devastated that `make` errored out.  You saved me with this!