# Lenovo ideapad 5 PRO 16ARH7 wifi doesn't work even after installing newest drivers

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, lenovo

### Main problem

Wifi does not even show up as an network option after multiple reboots and driver installations -> iwconfig returns nothing
lshw returns this:

```
~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
   description: Network controller
   product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: ioport:2000(size=256) memory:80900000-809fffff
```

### System information

**Wifi card info**

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
pcilib: Error reading /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:08.3/label: Operation not permitted
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b852]
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4853]
02:00.0 SD Host controller [0805]: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller  [1217:8621] (rev 01)
Subsystem: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller [1217:0002]
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

According to the command output above, my device has Realtek 10ec:b852 wifi + bluetooth combo card.
WirelessCat says that this card should work with rtw89 driver

### Neofetch

[Link to neofetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkFWB.png)

### Why is the kernel 6.0

On this particular lenovo keyboard didnt work unless i used the latest available daily kernel from ubuntu, mainline unfortunately didnt provide it either.

### What drivers I've tried

Both were installed exactly as per the github instructions.
I did not try them both at the same time. When i switched between them i uninstalled one and then rebooted before installing the other one.

- https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw8852be/
- https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89

I installed drivers without secure boot which is currently completely disabled along with all other bios security features(i triple checked)
Installations on both drivers were successful to the best of my knowledge and running

```
sudo modprobe -vr 8852be
sudo modprobe -v 8852be
```

returned no errors either.
`modinfo 8852be` shows the available options for the driver

### Similar posts that did not help

1. https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/w0txaa/no_wifi_on_lenovo_yoga_6_13/
2. [wifi Adapter not found realtek RTL8852BE WiFi 6 802.11ax PCIe in ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412219/wifi-adapter-not-found-realtek-rtl8852be-wifi-6-802-11ax-pcie-in-ubuntu-22-04/1412264#1412264)

EDIT: Tried installing Manjaro to take the drivers from it, same problem

Thank you for reading this far. I hope i provided all the necessary information.

Comment: Pop OS is not an official Ubuntu flavor and thus off-topic here.

Comment: [This article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1426695/wifi-not-working-on-ubuntu-22-04-1-with-dual-boot-on-lenovo-ideapad-3) worked for me (same model).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you could make lwfinger driver work, but I found this one that works fine with 6.0.9 mainline kernel:
https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be