# Wifi not working on Ubuntu 22.04.1 with dual boot on Lenovo IdeaPad 3

Tags: wireless

I installed Ubuntu in dual boot configuration alongside windows 11 in my Lenovo IdeaPad 3 Ryzen 5 5625u. Network adapter RTL8852BE.

Tried updating the kernel, and tried editing the ssl file as well. It also shows Bluetooth in the settings but does not discovered by any device and is not able to discover any device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a common problem for certain Realtek wifi chipsets. You can build your own driver here: https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be

First, you will need to `sudo apt install linux-headers-generic gcc make git` and you have to disable secure boot to insert unsigned kernel modules. Then, from the github readme:

```
git clone https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be.git
cd rtl8852be
make -j8
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8852be
```

If you don't want to disable secure boot, you will have to sign your own drivers - more info here: https://superuser.com/questions/1438279/how-to-sign-a-kernel-module-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Thanks for helping, It worked. 
Any idea why Realtek wifi chipset like this one face this problem?

Comment: The old drivers were undocumented and didn't meet the standards of code quality for the kernel. Fortunately, Realtek is finally making an effort to have newer chipsets included in mainline.

Comment: Can confirm solution working for following model as well: `Lenovo IdeaPad 5 Pro 16ARH7`.

Comment: @ThankYee I executed `sudo apt install linux-headers-generic gcc make git` but it shows `Unable to locate packages`. Because, my wifi adapter is not installed and I cannot connect to internet. I disabled secure boot, but then how to `insert unsigned kernel modules`?