# wifi Adapter not found Realtek RTL8852BE Wi-Fi 6 (2x2) in ubuntu 22.04 new HP G9 Free Dos Laptop

Tags: 22.04, laptop, hp, realtek-wireless, ubuntu-drivers

I am quite new in the Ubuntu world and while installing 22.04. on my new [HP G9 Free Dos](https://www.hp.com/de-de/shop/product.aspx?id=6s763ea&opt=abd&sel=ntb#detailedSpecs) laptop I got similar issue as described in this thread: [wifi Adapter not found realtek RTL8852BE WiFi 6 802.11ax PCIe in ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412219/wifi-adapter-not-found-realtek-rtl8852be-wifi-6-802-11ax-pcie-in-ubuntu-22-04)

I am just not sure if I can do the same or not as I have a HP not Lenovo

The result of my terminal command lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3 is:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b852]
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:88e3]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
```

Thanks - command `make` was not available so I did install it via `sudo apt install make` then running `make` said:

```
/bin/sh: 1: cc: not found
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
#rm -f .symvers.8852be
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.15.0-50-generic/build M=/home/administrator/rtl8852be  modules
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-50-generic“ wird betreten
arch/x86/Makefile:142: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
make[1]: gcc: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0
  You are using:           
/bin/sh: 1: gcc: not found
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
  CC [M]  /home/administrator/rtl8852be/platform/platform_linux_pc_pci.o
/bin/sh: 1: gcc: not found
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:297: /home/administrator/rtl8852be/platform/platform_linux_pc_pci.o] Fehler 127
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1900: /home/administrator/rtl8852be] Fehler 2
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-50-generic“ wird verlassen
make: *** [Makefile:637: modules] Fehler 2
```

Sorry for the german words - any easy way to switch to english?

Comment: I just searched for your WiFi adapter and it shows me there are a few questions on ask Ubuntu about it. The driver 10ec:b852 You may want to do the same and see if any of the questions and answers already on the site help you.

Comment: HI David, thanks for quick reply - I saw 2 with answers. I am not sure if I can just try what is suggested there or if I could damage anything which cannot be fixed afterwards.

Comment: Loading a driver can not damage hardware. Post the 2 you are thinking of trying.

Comment: <https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412219/wifi-adapter-not-found-realtek-rtl8852be-wifi-6-802-11ax-pcie-in-ubuntu-22-04> and/or <https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412450/network-driver-for-realtek-10ecb852>

Comment: Please be aware the first answer includes steps about reversing some user actions that are applicable only to that context. You can follow the second which is the same minus the initial steps not applicable to your situation.

Comment: Thanks - command make was not available so I did install it via `sudo apt install make`

Comment: Details added above as too much text

Comment: The absense of 'make', 'gcc' et al suggests that you first need to install build-essential. Then try again. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Great - after installing build essentials I could run make and it is working now - thanks for quick support. Very impressive.

Comment: WiFi was running well  a couple of days but since today again the message No Wi-Fi Adapter found. What can I do?

Comment: Found it by myself: ```cd rtl8852be
make clean
git pull
make
sudo make install``` But do I really need to do it every time when WLAN disappears?

Comment: Perhaps not. May we see a link to the file you are compiling?

Comment: hopefully that is what you expected: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/n4yVb3p7Gt/plain/

Comment: No, sorry. What I need to see is where you got the file rtl8852be. Did you download it from a website? From github? HRex39, perhaps??

Comment: I followed the instructions in (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412450/network-driver-for-realtek-10ecb852) so got it from GitHub - Yes HRex39

Answer (score 0):

You have compiled the driver for your currently running kernel version only. When a newer kernel version is installed as offered by Software Updater, you must recompile:

```
cd rtl8852be
make clean
git pull
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8852be
```

In order to avoid recompiling, the DKMS process is used.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support However, the HRex39 repository has no dkms.conf file nor does the README.md mention any DKMS procedure.

The probable successor here also has no DKMS mechanism: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw8852be