# Problem with driver package on rtl8852be

Tags: drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

I have an rtl8852be WiFi card. After some initial trouble with the software not working with the card I came across this thread: [wifi Adapter not found realtek RTL8852BE WiFi 6 802.11ax PCIe in ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412219/wifi-adapter-not-found-realtek-rtl8852be-wifi-6-802-11ax-pcie-in-ubuntu-22-04?newreg=f9fabfade71e4da1a98290c83bf78fcb)

This has worked for the last few months but after the last kernel update I now get the following message after recompiling:

```
elli@elli-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4:~/rtl8852be$ make
#rm -f .symvers.8852be
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.19.0-32-generic/build M=/home/elli/rtl8852be  modules
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-32-generic“ wird betreten
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
  You are using:           gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
  CC [M]  /home/elli/rtl8852be/platform/platform_linux_pc_pci.o
/home/elli/rtl8852be/platform/platform_linux_pc_pci.c: In function ‘pci_cache_wback’:
/home/elli/rtl8852be/platform/platform_linux_pc_pci.c:21:17: error: implicit declaration of function ‘pci_dma_sync_single_for_device’; did you mean ‘dma_sync_single_for_device’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   21 |                 pci_dma_sync_single_for_device(hwdev, *bus_addr, size,
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 dma_sync_single_for_device
/home/elli/rtl8852be/platform/platform_linux_pc_pci.c: In function ‘pci_cache_inv’:
/home/elli/rtl8852be/platform/platform_linux_pc_pci.c:30:17: error: implicit declaration of function ‘pci_dma_sync_single_for_cpu’; did you mean ‘dma_sync_single_for_cpu’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   30 |                 pci_dma_sync_single_for_cpu(hwdev, *bus_addr, size, direction);
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 dma_sync_single_for_cpu
/home/elli/rtl8852be/platform/platform_linux_pc_pci.c: In function ‘pci_get_bus_addr’:
/home/elli/rtl8852be/platform/platform_linux_pc_pci.c:39:29: error: implicit declaration of function ‘pci_map_single’; did you mean ‘dma_map_single’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   39 |                 *bus_addr = pci_map_single(hwdev, vir_addr, size, direction);
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                             dma_map_single
/home/elli/rtl8852be/platform/platform_linux_pc_pci.c: In function ‘pci_unmap_bus_addr’:
/home/elli/rtl8852be/platform/platform_linux_pc_pci.c:50:17: error: implicit declaration of function ‘pci_unmap_single’; did you mean ‘dma_unmap_single’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   50 |                 pci_unmap_single(hwdev, *bus_addr, size, direction);
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 dma_unmap_single
/home/elli/rtl8852be/platform/platform_linux_pc_pci.c: In function ‘pci_free_noncache_mem’:
/home/elli/rtl8852be/platform/platform_linux_pc_pci.c:97:17: error: implicit declaration of function ‘pci_free_consistent’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   97 |                 pci_free_consistent(pdev, size, vir_addr, *bus_addr);
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:257: /home/elli/rtl8852be/platform/platform_linux_pc_pci.o] Fehler 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1850: /home/elli/rtl8852be] Fehler 2
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-32-generic“ wird verlassen
make: *** [Makefile:637: modules] Fehler 2
```

Sorry for the bits in German. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This means that the driver is incompatible with the  5.19 kernel. For the future: you can add the `LANG=C` prefix to any command to get output in English, e.g. `LANG=C make`.

Comment: @Pilot6 thank you. It seems I messed up when getting the driver. According to the readme here: https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be I should have used `git clone https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be.git -b dev` instead of `git clone https://github.com/HRex39/` . How do I safely remove my current driver?

Comment: You don't need to remove it. Just delete the source directory.

Comment: @Pilot6 thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your driver didn't build for the 5.19 kernel.

Install another one by

```
git clone https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be.git -b dev
cd rtl8852be
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8852be
```

But you'll have to re-compile it after each kernel upgrade unless you create a DKMS module.