# Driver for Realtek RTL8852BE with no internet

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek

I got a laptop and I want to dual boot with Windows 11 and Linux Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Unfortunately I do not have a clue how to install a driver with no internet connection. My Wi-Fi card is not detected, I tried to fix it for several day but now I'm absolutely upset.

Wi-Fi card: Realtek RTL8852BE wifi 6 80211ax pcie adapter 1528648

I used [this article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1455396/problem-with-driver-package-on-rtl8852be) to fix a problem, but got errors to install built-essential with no internet.

Could someone please help to understand how to install a built-essential in my case?