# Wifi adapter for Realtek b852

Tags: 20.04, realtek, realtek-wireless

I purchased a new laptop with Ryzen 5 processor and installed Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS. I followed this guide to setup my wifi adapter: [wifi Adapter not found realtek RTL8852BE WiFi 6 802.11ax PCIe in ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412219/wifi-adapter-not-found-realtek-rtl8852be-wifi-6-802-11ax-pcie-in-ubuntu-22-04/1412264#1412264).

However, after building `rtl8852be`, when I try `sudo modprobe 8852be`, it gives me the error `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8852be': Operation not permitted`.

```
$ lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fcf00000-fcffffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@2:2
       logical name: enxa0cec8ea5aff
       serial: a0:ce:c8:ea:5a:ff
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=ax88179_178a driverversion=5.15.0-67-generic duplex=full ip=10.12.142.117 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

```
$ lspci | grep Network
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b852
```

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep -i rtw
(no output)
```

```
$ lsmod | grep rtw
rtw89_pci              49152  0
rtw89_core            995328  1 rtw89_pci
mac80211             1249280  2 rtw89_core,rtw89_pci
cfg80211              970752  2 rtw89_core,mac80211
```

How should I proceed?

### Edit

When I rebooted after switching off secure boot, I am now able to connect to WiFi.