# Add firmware with .bin file

Tags: drivers, wireless, kernel

I'm missing the driver for the Realtek RTL8852be Wifi Adapter. There are just the rtw8852a_fw.bin and rtw8852c_fw.bin files in the /lib/firmware/rtw89 folder and I need the rtw8852b_fw.bin file. I downloaded the rtw8852b_fw.bin from [git.kernel.org](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/rtw89)
and put it in the folder, but that doesn't fixed the issue. I tried a reboot and run sudo modprobe rtw8852b:

> modprobe: FATAL: Module rtw8852b not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-67-generic

I couldn't find any helpful information about how to install drivers with a .bin file.

Could someone point me in the right direction how to solve the problem?

Comment: I driver often consists of code *and* the firmware blob. From the information you gave, what you downloaded was *only* the blob, not the driver. What's the output from `modinfo rtw89_8852b`?

Comment: So it looks like that's for a newer kernel. It's available for Ubuntu Lunar but that's not officially supported until next month. Alternatively, you could try finding firmware on github but this usually requires some module compiling and/or DKMS installation. Installation is usually straightforward but you'd need to find something compatible with your current kernel and one that isn't too outdated or it probably won't compile.

Comment: You really have two questions here: first, how to install the firmware file and second, why isn't the driver installed and working. Please edit your question to tell us the exact process you followed to install the driver. I assume that you downloaded the driver here: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89 What did you do next? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Please see the comment at the git repository: "you can download the firmware from
https://lwfinger.com/download/rtw8852b_fw.bin, and copy it to /lib/firmware/rtw89/."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wifi Adapter not found realtek RTL8852BE WiFi 6 802.11ax PCIe in ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412219/wifi-adapter-not-found-realtek-rtl8852be-wifi-6-802-11ax-pcie-in-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: @popey modinfo doesn't find the modul. - I guess this is a dead end?

Comment: @Koque - no it just means the kernel you're running doesn't have the driver. As I said, the bin file is only half the story. There's other comments above suggesting how you can install the driver - but you have to do that manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My wifi is now working. I used the driver from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89, as chili555 advised.

Thanks popey for explaining why just copying the .bin file didn't work.